# Distinguishable Event tracking in function using Google Analytic

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm trying to add an event tracking in my code in HTML/JS web page. So each time that a button is clicked a function executed and for each such execution I want a different event tracker.

For example:
If it is the first click then increase the first counter.
if it is the second click, increase the second counter.
No need to worry here the number of such executions in no more then three.

So far the function looks like this (more or less):

```
    function next_click()
    {
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxx-x']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Follow', 'Facebook']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-x', '127.0.0.1');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
        if (document.getElementById("step" + (current_step + 1)) == undefined)
        return;
    if (!validate_step(current_step))
        return;
    document.getElementById("step" + current_step).style.display = "none";
    current_step++;
    page_count++;
    }
```

I'm having trouble configuring the events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The problem was that I wasn't using the following line:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Category', 'action','lable', value);
```

instead of the global tracking line:

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

So that each time the counter increased/decreased it never was send back to Google.
Now after adding this line, the event shows up.

And the way to distinguish between the event is simple by changing the *Category* field or/and the *Action* field.
For more reference, you can read here:
 [Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

Answer (score 0):

The onload event is only fired on the body tag, when the page finishes loading.
What you really want, is an event when the display status of your div changes.
Since such an event doesn't exist, you'll have to write some code that checks whether step2 is now being displayed in the click functions you already have.

Comment: Okay, that's seems not a problem. As I mentioned I have this variable. I can use it for checking. The question that remains is how then I use the tracking event

Comment: As I understand it, each push() invocation is a recording of one user interaction. You can just call it in your code whenever the right div appears.

Comment: I've added the whole block of Google code and now each time I click on a button I see the visits count increase although the problem is that I can't distinguish between them

Answer (score 0):

Are you initializing your GA using this code

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X', 'example.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: Yes. I do. I have it straight from the website. The tracking overall is working. I see the visits at the first page I land on